# Why can't we have a safe ISA?

Tags: security, memory-management, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, memory-safety

Accroding to this paper: https://doi.org/10.1109/SP.2013.13, Memory corruption bugs are one of the oldest problems in computer security. The lack of memory safety and type safety has caused countless bugs, causing billions of dollars and huge efforts to fix them.

But the root of C/C++'s memory vulnerability can trace down to the ISA level. At ISA level, every instruction can access any memory address without any fine grained safe check (only corase grained check like page fault). Sure, we can implement memory safe at a higher software level, like Java (JVM), but this leads to significant cost of performance. In a word, we can't have both safety and performance at the same time on existing CPUs.

My question is, why can't we implement the safety at the hardware level? If the CPU has a safe ISA, which ensures the memory safe by, I don't know, taking the responsbilities of `malloc` and `free`, then maybe we can get rid of the performance decline of software safe checking. If anyone professional in microelectronics can tell me, is this idea realistic?

Comment: For that to be possible, hardware would have to know about every object and its size, and be able to cache that structure in a way that allows efficient lookups to find the bounds.  Page tables (4k granularity, or larger in more modern ISAs) are already hard enough for hardware for hardware to cache efficiently for large programs, and that's without even considering which pointer goes with which object.

Comment: @PeterCordes You mean it may cost too much at hardware level, like the die area?

Comment: Check this! I also asked this question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpudesign/comments/woornu/why_cant_we_have_a_safe_isa/, and someone told me CHERI: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/.

Comment: Its not until tody that I know about the Intel iAPX 432: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_iAPX_432#Development. Thanks Intel for this interesting and meaningful lesson!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you mean, **it could make it impossible implement memory-unsafe languages like C in a normal way**.  e.g. every memory access would have to be to some object that has a known size?  I'd guess an operating system for such a machine might have to work around that "feature" by telling it that the entire address space was one large array object.  Or else you'd need some mechanism for a `read` system call to know the proper bounds of the object it's writing in the `copy_to_user()` part of its job.  And then there's other OS stuff like accessing the same physical page from different virtual pages.

The OP ([via asking on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpudesign/comments/woornu/why_cant_we_have_a_safe_isa/)) found the [CHERI project](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/) which is an attempt at this idea, involving "*... **revisit fundamental design choices** in hardware **and software** to dramatically improve system security.*"  Changing hardware alone can't work; compilers need to change, too.  But they were able to adapt "Clang/LLVM, FreeBSD, FreeRTOS, and applications such as WebKit," so their approach could be practical.  (Unlike the hypothetical versions I was imagining when writing other parts of this answer.)

CHERI uses "fine-grained memory protection", and "Language and compiler extensions" to implement memory-safe C and C++, and higher-level languages.

So it's not a drop-in replacement, and it sounds like you have to actively use the features to gain safety.  As I argue in the rest of the answer, hardware can't do it *alone*, and it's highly non-trivial even with software cooperation.  It's easy to come up with ways that wouldn't work. :P

---

For hardware-*enforced* memory-safety to be possible, hardware would have to know about every object and its size, and be able to cache that structure in a way that allows efficient lookups to find the bounds.  Page tables (4k granularity, or larger in more modern ISAs) are already hard enough for hardware for hardware to cache efficiently for large programs, and that's without even considering which pointer goes with which object.

Checking a TLBs as part of every load and store can be done efficiently, but checking another structure in parallel with that might be problematic.  Especially when the ranges don't have power-of-2 sizes and natural alignment, the way pages do, which makes it possible to build a TLB from content-addressable memory that checks for a match against each of several possible values for the high bits.  (e.g. a page is 4k in size, always starting at a 4k alignment boundary.)

> You mean it may cost too much at hardware level, like the die area?

Die area might not even be the biggest problem, especially these days.  It would cost *power*, and/or cost latency in very important critical paths such as L1d hit load-use latency.  Even if you could come up with some plausible way for software to make tables that hardware could check, or otherwise solve the other parts of this problem.

Modifying a page-table entry requires invalidating the entry, including TLB shootdown for other cores.  If every `free` (and some `malloc`) cost inter-core communication to do similar things for object tables, that would be very expensive.

**I think inventing a way for software to tell the hardware about objects would be an even bigger problem.**  `malloc` and `free` aren't something you can just build in to a CPU where memory addressing works anything like existing CPUs, or like it does in C.  Software needs to manage memory, it doesn't make sense to try to build that in to a CPU.  So then `malloc` and `free` (and `mmap` with file-backed mappings and shared memory...) need a way to tell the CPU about objects.  Seems like a mess.

---

**I think at best an ISA could provide more tools software can use to make bounds-checks cheaper.**  Perhaps some kind of extra semantics on loads/stores, like an extra operand for indexed addressing modes for load or store that takes a max?

At least if we want an  ISA to work anything like current ones, rather than work like a JVM or a Transmeta Crusoe and internally recompile for some real ISA.

[Intel's MPX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_MPX) ISA extension to x86 was an attempt to let software set up bound ranges, but it's been mostly abandoned due to lower performance than pure software.  Intel [even dropped it from their recent CPUs](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000059823/processors.html) (Not present in 10th Gen CPUs using 10nm lithography, or later.)

This is all just off the top of my head; I haven't searched for any serious proposals for how a system could plausibly work.

I don't think memory safety is something you can easily add after the fact to languages like C that weren't originally designed with it.

Comment: The most advanced implementation that I know of is called the "Dover inherently secure processor".   It has HW support for metadata that feeds into a parallel "security pipeline" that can implement many security policies. They developed a very sneaky pointer format that embeds the object length into a single 64-bit pointer, while metadata marks any excess memory allocations as unusable.  A nice presentation is at https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Wed1430-dover_riscv_jan2016_v3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Besides Intel's MPX, security ISA extensions for RISC-V exist, such as [SHORE](https://github.com/Lycheus/SHORE) and [HWST128](https://github.com/Lycheus/HWST128).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to "Code for malloc and free" at SO. Those commands are very, very far away from even being defined within an instruction set.